# Creating fields through a loop and using vars - WordPress Customizer

Tags: php, wordpress, customizer

I'm creating a new section in the Customiser section of WordPress. This section is called `Footer Logos`.

There's going to be 7 images in the footer of a website and I want the admin to have full control on what these images will be (which is why I'm doing it via the customiser).

Rather than creating 7 new controls via `add_control`, I'm trying to create them via a loop that will stop on the 7th iteration.

```html
public function footer_logos($customizer) {
    // Add our customizer section
    $customizer - > add_section(
        'foot_logos', array(
            'title' => __('Footer Logos', 'my_theme'),
            'priority' => 1100,
        )
    );

    // Add our settings
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
        $customizer - > add_setting('logo-$i');
    }


    for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
        $customizer - > add_control(
            new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
                $customizer, 'logo-$i', array(
                    'label' => __('Logo $i', 'my_theme'),
                    'description' => __('', 'my_theme'),
                    'section' => 'foot_logos',
                )
            )
        );
    }



}
```

Currently, only one field is showing with the title "Logo $i".

What I'm trying to achieve are 7 fields with the header "Logo 1", "Logo 2" etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
public function footer_logos($customizer) {
// Add our customizer section
$customizer - > add_section(
    'foot_logos', array(
        'title' => __('Footer Logos', 'my_theme'),
        'priority' => 1100,
    )
);

// Add our settings
for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
    $customizer - > add_setting('logo-'.$i);
}


for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
    $customizer - > add_control(
        new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
            $customizer, 'logo-'.$i, array(
                'label' => __('Logo '.$i, 'my_theme'),
                'description' => __('', 'my_theme'),
                'section' => 'foot_logos',
            )
        )
    );
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the variable $i you should use Double quotes. For example: `"logo-$i"`. Another way is like the answer above with `'logo-' . $i`.